# React exporting context returns Parsing error: Export 'SearchContextConsumer' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parsing, syntax-error

I am trying to create a context in order to pass data to another component without using props drilling, but when I export my consumer I get that `Parsing error: Export 'SearchContextConsumer' is not defined`
What seems to be the problem and how can I export it successfully?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        isSearched: false
    }

    SearchContext = React.createContext('context');
    SearchContextConsumer = SearchContext.Consumer;
    data = { searchResults: this.state.searchResults }

    Search = ({ children }) => (
        <SearchContext.Provider value={searchResults}>{children}</SearchContext.Provider>
    )

    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
                queryString: queryString,


            }).then(response => {

                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });

            });
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearched: true });
            window.location.href = '/blog/searchResults'
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { SearchContextConsumer }
export default Search;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks uneccessary complicated to me. Why don't you straight up export the created context and wrap the children
in the Provider directly:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
```

export const SearchContext = React.createContext();

```
class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        isSearched: false
    }

    data = { searchResults: this.state.searchResults }

    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
                queryString: queryString,


            }).then(response => {

                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });

            });
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearched: true });
            window.location.href = '/blog/searchResults'
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <SearchContext.Provider value={searchResults}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}
                />
            </SearchContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Components which want to use the context will have to be wrapped inside the Consumer:

```
import {SearchContext} from "Search"

<SearchContext.Consumer>
  {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
</SearchContext.Consumer>
```

Comment: tried doing it your way but i get the error that  Parsing error: Export 'SearchContext' is not defined

Comment: I made a mistake. The declaration of the store has to be like this: ```const SearchContext = React.createContext();```. I forgot to declare it as const. Please try again with this.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. ```SearchContext``` was defined in the class component. Because of the scope, the export statement outside the class had no idea what ```SearchContext``` is. I moved the declaration outside of the class to the top of the component. So you can directly export it and the class component has access to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export a property of a class this way.

I think the simplest and cleanest way to do what you have in mind is to create your `context` outside of your class like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SearchContext = React.createContext();

class Search extends Component {
    state = {
        searchResults: [],
        isSearched: false
    }



    data = { searchResults: this.state.searchResults }

    getSearchQuery = (event) => {
        const queryString = document.querySelector(
            ".search-input"
        ).value;

        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            axios.post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
                queryString: queryString,


            }).then(response => {

                this.setState({ ...this.state, searchResults: response.data });

            });
            this.setState({ ...this.state, isSearched: true });
            window.location.href = '/blog/searchResults'
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <SearchContext.Provider value={searchResults}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-input"
                    onKeyDown={(e) => this.getSearchQuery(e)}
                />
            </SearchContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export SearchContext.Consumer as SearchContextConsumer
export default Search;
```

---

and here is how you can do above functionality in `Function Component` which is more readable and less code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const SearchContext = React.createContext();

const Search = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    searchResults: [],
    isSearched: false
  });

  const getSearchQuery = event => {
    const queryString = document.querySelector(".search-input").value;

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3001/search", {
          queryString: queryString
        })
        .then(response => {
          setState({ ...state, searchResults: response.data });
        });
      setState({ ...state, isSearched: true });
      window.location.href = "/blog/searchResults";
    }
  };

  return (
    <SearchContext.Provider value={state.searchResults}>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="search-input"
        onKeyDown={e => getSearchQuery(e)}
      />
    </SearchContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Search;
```

now if you need to use your context data just do this inside `provider zone`:

```
const searchResults = React.useContext(SearchContext);
```